# Normal subgroups of group with order $p^2 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $p^2$ for a prime $p$. Show that
>
> - $(a)$ There exists a subgroup $N$ of order $p$ which is normal.
> - $(b)$ Any group $K$ of prime order is cyclic.
> - $(c)$ Groups $N$ and $G/N$ are both cyclic.

I've already established existence of at least one subgroup of order $p$ for $G$, but I don't know where to go though.

Also, for part $(b)$, it seems pretty easy which leads me to believe it may be a typo? The $G$ in the problem has $p^2$ order not $p$, is such a group still cyclic?

Comment: What have you tried (or how did you build this subgroup)? In response to your last question, no a group of order $p^2$ need not be cyclic. Consider $\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: I am not sure what to try, I could write out an arbitrary group of order p and start conjugating elements but I don't think that would achieve much.

Comment: Actually, that is one way to do it. Consider $N\leq G$, and let $G$ act on $N$ by conjugation. Now consider the set of conjugates of $N$. That is, $S=\{ g^{-1}Ng : g\in G\}$. What can we say about $\vert S\vert$? Does this tell us anything about $N$?

Comment: do you mean $N \subseteq G$? never seen the less than equal to notation for groups.

also, wouldn't it be conjugated like this:

$gNg^-1 : g \in G$ ?

Comment: Sorry, "$\leq$" is the standard notation for subgroups. Also, $gNg^{-1}$ will get you the same result for a proof. So instead, you could define $S=\{ gNg^{-1} : g\in G \}$.

Comment: really, i didn't know that. on both counts. that's interesting really, why would conjugation by $g$ and $g^-1$ be the same for something like this? what is so special about conjugation?

Comment: also, to answer your previous question, I would think that $|S|$ = $|G|$, since we are conjugating all of N by $g \in G$.

Comment: you have said you found a subgroup of order $p$.. could you see if it is normal?

Comment: Only way i know uses class equation to show that center of the group is not trivial. I dont know if you are familiar with it. You can find it on this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class#Example . Do you know why its enough?

Answer (score 2):

For part $(a)$, we can use the following result (see Section $4.2$, Corollary $5$ of Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra* for example.):

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be a subgroup with index $p$ where $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$, then $H$ is normal.

Here $p$ is the smallest prime which divides $|G|$ and $N$ has index $p$, so it is normal.

For part $(b)$, choose $x \in K\setminus\{e\}$, then $\langle x\rangle \leq K$ and by Lagrange's Theorem, $|\langle x\rangle|$ divides $|K| = p$. As $p$ is prime and $x \neq e$, $|\langle x\rangle| = p$ so $\langle x\rangle = K$; that is, $K$ is cyclic.

For part $(c)$ note that the subgroup $N$ that you found in part $(a)$ has order $p$ so by part $(b)$, $N$ is cyclic. As $N$ is normal, you can form the quotient group $G/N$ which has order $$|G/N| = \frac{|G|}{|N|} = \frac{p^2}{p} = p.$$ Again by part $(b)$, $G/N$ is cyclic.

Comment: I realize this answer is mainly to get the question off the unanswered list (thanks). But could you then also add a short note on part (a) (the OP seems to not have shown that the found subgroup is normal).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Sorry about that, I misread the post. I have added something now.